# phonegap get values from settings.bundle ios

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, settings.bundle

I am new to phonegap ,I have field called name_preference in settings.bundle, i am trying 
my code in main.js

```
 function deviceReady()  {
 window.plugins.applicationPreferences.get('name_preference',
 function(result)  {
         alert("We got a setting: " + result);
     },  function(error) {
         alert("Failed to retrieve a setting: " + error);
     } );
```

I had downloaded applicationPreferences.h ,applicationPreferences.m and placed in xcode 
then applicationPreferences.js and placed in js folder.
 help me out, how can i get value from settings.bundle from phonegap ios

Comment: Did you ever get preferences working? What was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> I had downloaded applicationPreferences.h ,applicationPreferences.m ...

Managing a plugin by hand is nearly impossible. Remove those files, and from the command line, run

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences.git
```

This will download the plugin, place it in the correct places, etc etc. No hassle for you!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer:

Placing the .m and .h files in Xcode is not enough. You will also need to right-click the Project Navigator pane in Xcode and click "Add Files...". Then, select the .m and .h files. Xcode will now include them in the build.